# Why does my Dell EMC PowerVault ME4 4024 not provide the correct amount of storage?

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, storage

I am configuring a Dell EMC PowerVault ME4 4024 with 10 11TB drives, using RAID6. In the management software it shows that we have 88TB available, the expected 20% reduction, but when the ME4 is mounted as a file system only 86TB is available.

We have a similar issue with our ME 4084, where a pool with 125TB available storage only 114TB is usable when mounted.

We have some older 3xxx series datastores as well, but they don't have this capacity reduction that we are facing with the 4xxx series.

The server we are using is RHEL7.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two points here.

First this is the usual, old and well known confusion between TeraBytes (TB) and TebiBytes (TiB). Hard drive are sold by their manufacturers by their size in TB (thousand billions of bytes). However with most operation systems (but MacOS) and storage tools sizes are reported in TiB (2 to the power of 40 bytes). The difference is significant: 1 TiB equals 1.099 TB.

That's why your 12 TB drives show up as roughly 10.91 TiB. So your 10 drives RAID-6 array has an actual capacity of

```
 8 x 10.91 = 87.28 TiB
```

Second, you formatted your array. Maybe used LVM, too. Each additional layer requires its own storage. Default filesystem for RedHat 7.7 is XFS. XFS requires quite a lot of space to store filesystem information, reserving space for billions of potential inodes, file names and metadata, plus filesystem structure. Typically about 2 GiB per TiB of managed storage.

So now your **87.28 TiB** array is reduced by a couple hundreds GiB more. Which depending upon the way you compute size, can be under 87 TiB and therefore 86 TiB then some.

Comment: Would that also explain the disproportionate size difference on the larger datastore? Losing 11TiB to filesystem information seems excessive. According to your explanation, we'd only be losing around half a TiB worst case.

Also, is there a way to check how much space XFS is reserving for filesystem information?

Comment: @William What wazoox is telling you is that you are just a "victim of mathematical confusion". **125 TB** = 125*10^12 bytes = 113.68 * 2^40 bytes = **113.68 TiB** This calculation just converts **TB** (the marketing HDD sitze value) to **TiB** which is commonly used to display disk sizes in computers. There is not one byte used for any file-system in this calculation!

Comment: That would do it, found where I can change the unit in the management software and now the sizes match up.